# What is the best angular way to ensure that all select dropdown fields are completed?

Tags: angularjs

In my application there are multiple select dropdowns are present as below.

**html**

```
<span class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyEveryWeekDay" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n.dayOfMonth for n in weeksInMonthYear track by n.occuranceNo" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>First</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyEveryDayInWeek" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n.weekFull for n in daysInWeeksYear track by n.weekShortName" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>Monday</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="extraWord col-md-2">of every</span>
<span class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyMonth" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:12" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>01</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Like this a lot of dropdowns are there, so i want to check if any select field value is empty then it will not navigate to next page and it will show an error message. I am unable to use regular angular form validation because these dropdowns are present in different form fields. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple "require" for it. If you use require than you are not able to empty that field and not navigate to next page.

Hope this this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

**Html**

```
<span class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyEveryWeekDay" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n.dayOfMonth for n in weeksInMonthYear track by n.occuranceNo" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>First</option>
    </select>
     <span class="error">{{yearlyError}}</span>
</span>
<span class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyEveryDayInWeek" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n.weekFull for n in daysInWeeksYear track by n.weekShortName" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>Monday</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error">{{yearlyWeekError}}</span>
</span>
<span class="extraWord col-md-2">of every</span>
<span class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="yearlyMonth" name="everyMinute" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:12" ng-class="{'submitted': formSubmit}" ng-change="getYearlyValue()" select-placeholder>
        <option value="" disabled>01</option>
    </select>
     <span class="error">{{yearlyMonthError}}</span>
</span>
```

**Js Controller**

```
// To show form error
$scope.yearlyError  = false;
$scope.yearlyWeekError = false;
$scope.yearlyMonthError = false;

// When navigate btn is clicked
$scope.navigate = function () {   
  if ($scope.yearlyEveryWeekDay === undefined || $scope.yearlyEveryDayInWeek === undefined || $scope.yearlyMonth === undefined) {
    if ($scope.yearlyEveryWeekDay == undefined) {
        $scope.yearlyError  = true;
    }
    if ($scope.yearlyEveryDayInWeek == undefined) {
        $scope.yearlyWeekError  = true;
    }
    if ($scope.yearlyMonth == undefined) {
        $scope.yearlyMonthError  = true;
    } 
 } else {
    $location.path('/next');
 }
}
```

Comment: Can i use something like angular foreach kind thing to iterate through the select dropdowns and check the value of that dropdown ,  if it is emprty then come out of that loop if not continue ? @digit

Comment: I think you cannot because it is not an array. Other than that, you can use scope.watch that will detect the model changes. I just give u suggestion.